# continue to next qtn and keep count of correct answer to write to file

Tags: c#

I'm creating a quiz in c#. I have the questions writing to a list box, and then name, email and number of correct answers to a file. The program runs, will write the name and email and displays the first question, but it will not proceed to the next questions and will not count when the correct answer is chosen. I would like it to proceed to the next question immediately after an answer is selected. The count will be calculated when the test is submitted. Can anyone give me a clue what I'm missing? Here's what I have.

```
    public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

        string[] firstAnswer = new string[] {"***"};
        string[] secondAnswer = new string[] {"***"};
        string[] thirdAnswer = new string[] {"***"};
        int count = 0;
        bool found = false;
        int index = 0;

   private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


   private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


       {

           string name;
           string email;


           name = nameTextBox.Text;
           email = emailTextBox.Text;

           StreamWriter outputFile;
           outputFile = File.AppendText("Submission_List.txt");

           outputFile.WriteLine(name);
           outputFile.WriteLine(email);


           outputFile.Close();



           string[] question1 = new string[] {
        "Who is a Silk Worm?", " ",
         "1) Beebo", "2) Bael", "3) Onycho", "4) Ilion",};

           {
               listBox1.DataSource = question1;
           }

           if (question1 != firstAnswer)

           {
               found = false;
           }

           else

              while (count <= 5)
            {
           count = count + 1;
            }

           {
               found = true;
               count++;
           }

           string[] question2 = new string[] {
         "What does Sapience mean?", " ",
          "1) Beauty", "2) Cursed", "3) Properity", "4) Wisdom" };

           {
               listBox1.DataSource = question2;
           }

           if (question2 != secondAnswer)
           {
               found = false;
           }

           else

               while (count <= 5)
               {
                   count = count + 1;
               }

           {
               found = true;
               count++;
           }

           string[] question3 = new string[] {
        "What is Tainou?", " ", "1) Imp", "2) Wolf", "3) Trow", "4) Elf" };

           {
               listBox1.DataSource = question1;
           }

           if (question3 != thirdAnswer)
           {
               found = false;
           }

           else

               while (count <= 5)
               {
                   count = count + 1;
               }

           {
               found = true;
               count++;
           }
       }
   }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                count = count++;

                StreamWriter outputFile;
                outputFile = File.AppendText("Submission_List.txt");
                outputFile.WriteLine(count++);

                outputFile.Close();

            }

               private void exitButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
               {
                this.Close();
               }
            }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really missing structure and is honestly, quite a mess.

After showing the first question, the code checks

```
if (question1 != firstAnswer)
```

which would always be false. After that it sets 'found' to true, add 1 to count. Then it would 'initialize' second question check

```
if (question2 != secondAnswer)
```

which would always be false. Sets 'found' to true, again, and add 1 to count and so forth.

If those above statements weren't false, it would always add 5 to the variable 'count'. I really don't see the reason why....

The selected index change event handler is a pretty good start, too bad it's empty. Basically, you'd initialize the first question, then WAIT for the user to answer -> selecting the index would fire up the change event handler, then move on to next question.

Put a breakpoint on the start of you button1 click event handler and I think you learn much more how your code actually handles.

Comment: yeah... sorry, but this is my first c# class and you lost me.  I wrote if (question1 != firstAnswer) to narrow down the correct answer in the else statement. Do I need a while or foreach statement?

Comment: You need to check the class material on 'event handlers' and 'user interaction'. Your code is just basically just running through (did you try debugging?)

Comment: it runs, it just won't progress to the next question and keep track of the count. It writes the name and email.

Comment: And it what point in your code you are actually WAITING for the user to answer? Please, add a breakpoint as suggested and go through the code line by line and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I recommend doing a basic form with 5 different questions (listboxes) and checking all the answers in the submit event. If you want the user to see just one question at the time, you can hide the other questions and show the next one after user has answered (visibility changes could be done in the listbox change event handler).

Comment: I wanted it to go to the next question once the user answers the question. I'm committed to this for my final. Worse case scenario I simplify it.

Comment: By using visibility changes, as suggested, you will get the user experience you are after. You can also use just one listbox but that would just bring more unnecessary complexity in your code. In any case, you really need to learn about event handlers.

Comment: I'm sure I need to learn a lot about a lot, but today I need to complete something I can turn in. Can you please offer examples?

Comment: This is really not the place to get your homework done for you. But this should give the basic idea I'm after: http://pastebin.com/kFbxc0aB

Comment: know, and honestly I'm desperate.  I really appreciate your time.